# win32gui get window content (internet explorer_server)

Tags: python, win32gui

For the extraction of text from a chat window I started off by gathering the window handles.
I managed doing this by the following code:

```
import time, win32gui
def callback(hwnd, IEServers):
    if win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd) == 'Internet Explorer_Server':
         IEServers.append(hwnd)
             print "IE server found:", hwnd
time.sleep(3)
mainHwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
IEServers = []
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(mainHwnd, callback, IEServers)
for serv in IEServers:
    print win32gui.GetClassName(serv)
```

Next thing I want to do is get the content (inner html?) as a string.

I believe it can be done via a IHTMLDocument2 object.
Info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q249232

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Maybe not exactly what you want but should get you on your way:

```
import time, win32gui
import win32com.client

time.sleep(2)
mainHwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

s = win32com.client.Dispatch("Shell.Application")
for w in s.Windows():
    if int(w.Hwnd) == mainHwnd:
        print w.LocationURL
        print w.Document.body.innerText
        print w.Document.body.innerHTML
        break
```

I think innerText is what you want, but I included several attributes so you can take your pick. This will only work with IE, of course.

Comment: This doesn't work. The window is part of a  bigger interface, which is not a internet explorer_server class..

Comment: Well I must have misunderstood your situation. Sorry it didn't help.